# Water Quality Data Acquisition Sources

Tags: watershed, data, lakes, waterways

I was wondering what sources are available, or if anyone has water quality data for the Great Lakes and specifically Lake Ontario?

We are interested in mapping Phosphorus, Organic Matter, Nitrogen and Dissolved Oxygen concentrations in Lake Ontario as they relate to algal blooms and hypoxia.

Comment: You can ask this on Stack Exchange's[Open Data Site](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/3361/6229

Answer (score 1):

You could check EPA's WATERS program:

http://water.epa.gov/scitech/datait/tools/waters/data/index.cfm

USGS also has a water monitoring program.